# what is the difference between a kernel process and a user process?

Tags: unix, process

I read it in Advanced programming in unix system by R.Stevens, that swapper is a kernel process and init is a user process.how are these both different from each other(kernel and system processes).can anyone please define them?

Comment: I point out that some non-Unix systems have no kernel processes and are entirely interrupt driven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-space processes have its own virtual address space.

Kernel processes or threads do not have their own address space, they operate within kernel address space only. And they may be started before the kernel has started any user process (e.g. init).